# Why I can't show all the specific column I want to echo

Tags: php, html, sql

This is my function

```
function getPdSectionChief(){
  /* get PD section Chief*/
  global $geotag_table, $wpdb, $current_user;
  $qry = "SELECT * FROM mirdc_pd_sectChief";
  $desc = $wpdb->get_results( $qry );
  return $desc;
}
```

after fetching, I am trying to show the data through my web

```
$geteeId = getPdSectionChief();
echo $geteeId->sect_id;
```

but it shows nothing :/ ..

but when i`am using the var_dump it show the array ..

Comment: Loop it so that you may display each item in the array

Comment: ohh dumb of me thank you sr

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, based from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php), don't really know if this is correct, I don't use `mysqli` but you can start from here

```
while ($row = $geteeId ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        foreach ($row as $r)
        {
            print "$r ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
```